# How can I filter with multiple criteria as they are set in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I have the user enter the filter criteria and the data get filtered incrementally?

I've used:
`=filter(Datasets!X2:AV,(Datasets!AA2:AA=B11) + (Datasets!AD2:AD=C11))`

...and this approach:
`=filter(Datasets!X2:AV,(xmatch(Datasets!AA2:AA,filter($B$10:$L$10,$B$11:$L$11))*(xmatch(Datasets!AD2:AD,C11))`

[Here is the sheet with data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

IIRC - the filter function doesn't support multiple criteria within a single range directly, so try using multiple filter functions and combine their results using the multiplication operator (*) instead of the addition operator (+).

```
=FILTER(Datasets!X2:AV, (Datasets!AA2:AA=B11) * (Datasets!AD2:AD=C11))
```

Datasets!X2:AV represent the range of data you want to filter, Datasets!AA2:AA represent the range for the first filter criteria, and Datasets!AD2:AD represents the range for the second filter criteria.

enter the filter criteria in cells B11 and C11, the formula will filter the data based on those criteria. The multiplication operator (*) is the logical "AND" operator, so both filter conditions must be true for a row to be included in the filtered results.

Answer (score 1):

***Updated formula:***

```
=query({F2:I};"where 1=1" 
             &if(len(B2); " AND Col1= '"&B2&"'";)
             &if(len(C2); " AND Col2= '"&C2&"'";)
             &if(len(D2); " AND Col4= date'"&text(D2;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'";);0)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Quick thing I ran into. If one column of the dataset doesn't have any entry, it doesn'tfilter the data, even though I haven't set the criteria for that column. How could I overcome that limitation? Thanks a million!

Comment: Try the updated formula.